# Shopify help - meta title

Tags: javascript, ruby, seo, shopify, liquid

Im working as a SEO and I'm working with Shopify for the first time.
I'm having difficulties with the meta titles on the site.

I generated "WebSite Auditor", the instrument shows that the site has too long titles. Okay I checked them and saw that Shopify has added the main meta title to the title i have written. What? Why?

For example, let's say the name of the site is called "**NOTEBOOK**" with main title - "**Fashionable notebooks**".
I want to name a meta SEO title of a category or a product, for example as: "**Notebooks with white sheets | NOTEBOOK**" . For some reason, Shopify decides that it has to attach the main meta title to it, like that: **"Notebooks with white sheets | NOTEBOOK - Fashionable notebooks**"
Why? Why is it making my life difficult. How can I remove the autogenerated "**Fashionable notebooks**" from the names of the categories.
Weird thing is that it doesn't generate it on all of the product meta titles. It does also generate it on the "Blog" category.
How can I remove it?

Comment: First, you have to check the meta title in the theme.liquid

Comment: The client is using Showcase 4.1.0, I still can't find where the main title is and why is it automatcailly generating?

Comment: Can you share your site and page URL?